# Kindle Fire and disable_keyguard permission

Tags: android, permissions, kindle-fire

So based on https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire Kindle Fire is NOT supporting disable_keyguard permission.

But I want that my application runs both on normal android devices and on kindle. Is there any simple solution to this problem?

And this permission is a must have so I can't just remove it from application.

Comment: Why are you disabling the keyguard?

Comment: If my application is active when phone goes to "sleep" I want that user only presses power key and he is instantly in application again without unlocking the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just surround disableKeyguard() call with try catch and perform some additional logic there.

```
KeyguardManager kgm = (KeyguardManager) Application.getSystemService(Application.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = kgm.newKeyguardLock(VIEW_LOG_TAG);
try{
    kl.disableKeyguard();
}
catch (SecurityException e)
{
    //kindle code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the context is of your application, but how about a [Wake Lock?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)  This could cost you some battery life though.

Comment: I am using wake lock too in combination with keyguard.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two editions of your app, one for the Fire and one for your existing targets. You could accomplish this by putting the bulk of your logic in an Android library project, shared between two regular Android projects (one with the keyguard feature, one without).

Comment: Isn't that a mess to fix and upgrade after you split an application in 2 separate projects?

Comment: @Gapipro: Is it somewhat more complicated than having a single project? Yes. You are welcome to not support the Fire if you do not wish to take on this complexity. Or, you are welcome to drop this feature if you do not wish to take on this complexity.

Comment: some like that yea. Not worth it at all if this is the only way.